# Django project structure in Eclipse (3 layers)

Tags: django, eclipse

**Eclipse: Neon Release (4.6.0)**

**Django: 1.10.4 (though, not important).**

I start a new Django project in Eclipse.

File -> New -> Project -> PyDev Django Project.

And now I get a three-layer structure.

For example (with an application "home" already added):

```
michael@ThinkPad:~/workspace/MyProject$ tree
.
└── MyProject
    ├── home
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── manage.py
    └── MyProject
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __pycache__
        │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
        │   └── settings.cpython-35.pyc
        ├── settings.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

Look: MyProject / MyProject / MyProject.

I haven't used Eclipse for some years. If I'm not mistaken, in bygone days Eclipse organized a two-layer structure. If I wanted a three-layer structure, I first created the project in terminal through "django-admin startproject". Then imported the project. And I changed Pythonpath in Eclipse (String Substitution Variables).

I understand that the top layer is for control version system.

What I can't understand: why Eclipse organizes it for me. Whether they decided that this is the best practice and now they follow it? Then why PyCharm creates a two-layer structure. Why django-admin itself creates a two-layer structure. I would say, Eclipse is overenthusiastic in this matter.

I mean, three-layer structure is not a classical one. If a programmer wants a three-layer structure, let him/her make it by hand.

Look here: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html
The documentation for PyDev. They write that they use django-admin.py startproject. So, why should I get a three-layer structure then. Strange.

I have a bad feeling that maybe there is an option in Eclipse where the number of layer is set. But I can't remember changing such an option.

Could you help me investigate this problem. Does your Eclipse also organizes a three-layer structure through File -> New -> Project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an old Eclipse user, I would suggest you not to use Eclipse :) By now, I think [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is the de facto IDE to work with Django.

As regards the project structure you should take a look at [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) to better organize your code.

Comment: I can't afford PyCharm Professional Edition. But I can use Community Edition to launch Django. In Run/Debug Configurations I can set script to manage py and script parameters as runserver. Then Django can be launched and the code debugged. But no smart code auto completion and no template debugging. I was thinking over Eclipse and PyCharm Community Edition. And somehow decided in favour of Eclipse. Do you think PyCharm Community Edition is better?